# Why is server.rb throwing this error in terminal

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments

I am following along with [this stripe tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2PJTcShgBps) but the server.rb in the example from Stripe's Github is throwing an error when I run **Ruby server.rb**

I am very new to ruby so I could be doing things wrong.

**What I did was:**

- Installed Ruby, Rails, Stripe CLI, Sinatra, and dotenv
- Downloaded the example from the site by typing Stripe samples create
  developer-office-hours
- cd'd into the server directory and ran ruby
  server.rb

**this is the error**

```
1: from server.rb:10:in '<main.'
server.rb:10:in 'join': no implicit conversation of nil into string (TypeError)
```

**here is the server.rb file**

```
require 'stripe'
require 'sinatra'
require 'dotenv'

# Replace if using a different env file or config
Dotenv.load
Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']

set :static, true
set :public_folder, File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ENV['STATIC_DIR'])
set :views, File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), ENV['STATIC_DIR'])
set :port, 4242

get '/' do
  content_type 'text/html'
  send_file File.join(settings.public_folder, 'index.html')
end

post '/webhook' do
  # You can use webhooks to receive information about asynchronous payment events.
  # For more about our webhook events check out https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks.
  webhook_secret = ENV['STRIPE_WEBHOOK_SECRET']
  payload = request.body.read
  if !webhook_secret.empty?
    # Retrieve the event by verifying the signature using the raw body and secret if webhook signing is configured.
    sig_header = request.env['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = nil

    begin
      event = Stripe::Webhook.construct_event(
        payload, sig_header, webhook_secret
      )
    rescue JSON::ParserError => e
      # Invalid payload
      status 400
      return
    rescue Stripe::SignatureVerificationError => e
      # Invalid signature
      puts "⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed."
      status 400
      return
    end
  else
    data = JSON.parse(payload, symbolize_names: true)
    event = Stripe::Event.construct_from(data)
  end
  # Get the type of webhook event sent - used to check the status of PaymentIntents.
  event_type = event['type']
  data = event['data']
  data_object = data['object']

  if event_type == 'some.event'
    puts "  Webhook received!"
  end

  content_type 'application/json'
  {
    status: 'success'
  }.to_json
end
```

Comment: Odds are pretty good that `ENV['STATIC_DIR']` isn't set.

Comment: am new to Ruby - did a google search - couldn't find anything on a first pass - is that an environment variable

Comment: how would I set it?

Comment: It is an environment variable, yes.  There are a number of different environment variables that need to be set here in order for this to work.

Comment: yes turned out there was no .env file or at least that's what i seem to have done to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `stripe login`

   This is a crucial step.
2. `stripe samples create adding-sales-tax`
3. `cd adding-sales-tax/server`
4. `bundle install`

   If you don't have bundler, `gem install bundler`
5. `bundle exec ruby server.rb`
6. Open http://localhost:4242

Comment: Yes thanks - at some point I figured it out - not sure what I did, I'm a bit bamboozled at this point from all the Stripe examples I've tried but I can definitely say that the information you've listed here looks like it's missing from the Stripe video or at least hard to see. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain step 5 please? ( bundle exec ) - the video was doing ruby server.rb

Comment: also am i wrong or do we need to start by installing stripe CLI in the first place though ( even though bundler seems to install it later too ?? but otherwise how would your step 1 work ?)

Comment: sorry for all the comments but since this is the accepted answer I might as well mention that the .env file was either missing or needed editing with the keys

Comment: `bundle exec` ensures that you are using the gems installed in step 4. Bundler installs stripe gem, which is different from stripe CLI.

Comment: wow - they bill the entire "Stripe Checkout" as being easy ( comparatively ) - which I guess it could be .... but the documentation is a bit of a puzzle lot of key bits of information like that that I didnt come across -